# jQuery Sortable (Drag-n-Drop) Dashboard Containers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

## Scenario:

I'm trying to create a dashboard of sorts which will have widgets of varying sizes. I would like the user to be able to arrange their widgets to their liking.

I have been trying to implement jQuery UI's **sortable** interaction, using the **[portlets](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets)** example, but I'm having some trouble.

[image]

## What's Working:

I can drag and drop/rearrange containers between columns within the same row.

## What's NOT Working:


I cannot drag containers between rows.

## My Question:


How can I enable dragging/dropping between rows *and* columns?

## jsFiddle Demo:


http://jsfiddle.net/SWUTR/

---

**Relevant HTML:**

```
<div class="column">
    <div class="container span2"></div>
    <div class="container span2"></div>
</div>
<div class="column">
    <div class="container span1"></div>
    <div class="container span2"></div>
    <div class="container span1"></div>
</div>
<div class="column">
    <div class="container span4"></div>
</div>
```

**Relevant CSS:**

```
.column .container {
    float:left;
    margin:5px;
    min-width:100px;
    height:250px;
    background:#39F;    
}
    .column .container.span1 {
        width:calc(25% - 10px); 
        background:#6CC;
    }
    .column .container.span2 {
        width:calc(50% - 10px); 
        background:#6F6;
    }
    .column .container.span3 {
        width:calc(75% - 10px); 
        background:#99C;
    }
    .column .container.span4 {
        width:calc(100% - 10px);
        background:#33C;    
    }
```

**Relevant jQuery:**

```
$(".column").sortable({
    connectWith: ".column"
});
$(".column").disableSelection();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that the problem is in CSS. 
It will work when you add the following line to your .js :

```
$(".column").addClass("ui-helper-clearfix");
```

From the documentation:

> .ui-helper-clearfix: Applies float wrapping properties to parent elements

http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137970/jQuery%20UI%20CSS%20Framework

Comment: Genius! Serious props for hunting this down. I was convinced it was a much bigger issue. You're the best!